# Calendar icon implementation into TableViewcontroller

Tags: ios, uitableview

Imagine that you table viewController and you have element  called "settingDate" in one of the row, I would like to add calendar icon on the left side of "settingDate" row but it should show current date inside? Any ideas to implement?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an image of the calendar icon without the number as the table cell's image view. Then add a label as a subview of the cell.imageView and update the label's text with an NSDate.